# How to prevent app layout changes when user change display size from the android setting application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-context, context-configuration

Currently, I am developing one android app so in that, I need to implement such functionality that prevents layout scaling whenever user change display size from the android device setting app. [image]

I am using the below library for font size and view size.
For font size https://github.com/intuit/ssp
For view size https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: Use constraint layout for best results.

Answer (score 0):

if you need your text to fix size for all screens, you'll have to use `dp`.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskUseDP) is the documentation.

> To preserve the visible size of your UI on screens with different
>   densities, you must design your UI using density-independent pixels
>   (dp) as your unit of measurement. One dp is a virtual pixel unit
>   that's roughly equal to one pixel on a medium-density screen (160dpi;
>   the "baseline" density). Android translates this value to the
>   appropriate number of real pixels for each other density.

Comment: My friend I am using DP for view size and SP for text size this is basic.

Comment: Yes, If you want to fix the size of the text for the app change sp -> dp. Because `sp` will be changed if you make the changing from the setting to large fonts. To prevent this you need to define the text size in dp's

Comment: Font scaling is working fine I just need to fix layout size scaling.

Comment: @FalduJaldeep you mean to say "ssp" and "sdp" (which are libraries) here, not sp and dp.